# Eclipse-Cannot instantiate the type JsonFactory

Tags: json, servlets, google-signin, server-side

I am working in a project, which needs to be logged in with google. Where I use a servlet to authenticate the user. In my servlet , I am getting the error **Cannot instantiate the type JsonFactory**.

Here is my code:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;

public class IdTokenVerifierAndParser {
private static final String GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "_id_";

public static GoogleIdToken.Payload getPayload (String tokenString) throws Exception {

    JsonFactory jacksonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    
    GoogleIdTokenVerifier googleIdTokenVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier(new NetHttpTransport(), jacksonFactory);

    GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(jacksonFactory, tokenString);

    if (googleIdTokenVerifier.verify(token)) {
        GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = token.getPayload();
        if (!GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.equals(payload.getAudience())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Audience mismatch");
        } else if (!GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.equals(payload.getAuthorizedParty())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Client ID mismatch");
        }
        return payload;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("id token cannot be verified");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JsonFactory`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory) is an abstract class. Abstract classes in Java can't be instantiated. You need to instantiate some concrete class that extends it.

Also, by the variable name `jacksonFactory` I assume you wanted to use the Jackson implementation of this factory. It's [marked as deprecated in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory), with the recommendation to use [`GsonFactory`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory) implementation instead.

```java
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

...

JsonFactory gsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
```